# Is there a way to generate a Web Query from multiple URL's without hardcoding the value in Excel?

Tags: json, excel, vba, automation

I am trying to automate a process where I download JSON data from my company's git repository and display it in excel. One of the things I need to do in the process is to create a new Query from a web address, and this needs to be able to change depending on what git repository the script user desires.  I chose to record a macro, and paste the web address into the URL textbox, which works. The problem is that the macro doesn't record the process of pasting from the clipboard, it only recognizes that text has been added, thinking that I intentionally want ONE specific web address to be hard coded into the macro instead of the act of pasting, which is what I really want. Is there a good way to avoid hardcoding a given URL into the New Query->From Web tab in Excel, and have the ability to keep the macro while adjusting the URL value?

Here is my VBA code with the URL and Token values removed:

```
   Sub JSONtoEXCEL()
'
' JSONtoEXCEL Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+J
'
    'Range( _
     '   "Table4[[#Headers],[http://URL]]" _
      '  ).Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "http://URL"
    Range("B1").Select
    ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add Name:= _
        "issues?state=open&access_token=token#", _
        Formula:= _
        "let" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "Source = Json.Document(Web.Contents(""" & Sheets("Sheet1").Range("$B$1").Value & """))" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Converted to Table"" = Table.FromList(Source, Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error)," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Expanded Column1"" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#""Converte" & _
        "d to Table"", ""Column1"", {""id"", ""url"", ""html_url"", ""number"", ""user"", ""original_author"", ""original_author_id"", ""title"", ""body"", ""ref"", ""labels"", ""milestone"", ""assignee"", ""assignees"", ""state"", ""is_locked"", ""comments"", ""created_at"", ""updated_at"", ""closed_at"", ""due_date"", ""pull_request"", ""repository""}, {""id"", ""url"", """ & _
        "html_url"", ""number"", ""user"", ""original_author"", ""original_author_id"", ""title"", ""body"", ""ref"", ""labels"", ""milestone"", ""assignee"", ""assignees"", ""state"", ""is_locked"", ""comments"", ""created_at"", ""updated_at"", ""closed_at"", ""due_date"", ""pull_request"", ""repository""})" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "in" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Expanded Column1"""
    Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
    With ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:=Array( _
        "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location=""issues?state=open&access_token=token#" _
        , "29f0ca0d90"";Extended Properties="""""), Destination:=Range("$A$1")). _
        QueryTable
        .CommandType = xlCmdSql
        .CommandText = Array( _
        "SELECT * FROM [issues?state=open&access_token=token#]" _
        )
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .PreserveColumnInfo = False
        .ListObject.DisplayName = _
        "issues_state_open_access_token_token#"
        If Index = ctr Then
        Else
            .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
        End If
        
    End With
    Selection.ListObject.QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False 'line that messes up
    Range("issues_state_open_access_token_token#" _
        ).Select
    Range("C6").Activate
    With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlGeneral
        .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
        .WrapText = True
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .IndentLevel = 0
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
        .MergeCells = False
    End With
End Sub
```

This code was generated by recording a macro and going through the process of loading in the JSON data to excel. I attempted to replace the string URL with reference to a cell that contains the URL. I get the error: "run-time error: '1004' The name 'Source' wasn't recognized. Make sure its spelled correctly.

When I replace the reference to the cell containing the URL with the literal URL this error goes away. I have also tried changing the way I reference the cell (absolute addressing, using a "&" to pass the coordinate as a reference, removing the quotation marks, etc.).

edit: I replaced the code with the most up to date changes and tried to fix formatting issues. **The token number has been replaced with *token#* and the URL has been replaced with *URL***

Comment: I can manually query the website, the issue is that I need to be able to find a way to access any website I choose, be that copying and pasting, editing the VBA code and trying to reference a cell with the address inside, etc. I'm not sure if there's something simple I'm missing but that was my idea for a solution.

Comment: @CalebGibson So you need a way for user to input the URL? Maybe [Inputbox](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.inputbox) if that's the case? Or paste the url in a specific cell .

Comment: @RaymondWu I tried simply pasting the URL in a cell, but you cant seem to use the coordinates of a cell as the value when adding a web query. The only input available is the URL textbox where you can type into or paste into.

Comment: Yes I don't think you can do that (although I'm pretty new in web query). I think this is doable in VBA and since I'm assuming that you are doing this in VBA.. (hence the tag), if you have a code, please edit your question and include them in. @CalebGibson

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `Range("B1").Value` is within the the quoted text it won't be interpolated to it's value.

Change this

```vb
& "Source = Json.Document(Web.Contents(Range("B1").Value)) & 

to 

& "Source = Json.Document(Web.Contents(""" & Range("B1").Value & """))," &
```

when corrected your Power Query should look like this

```vb
let
Source = Json.Document(Web.Contents("http://URL")),
    #"Converted to Table" = Table.FromList(Source, Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error),
    #"Expanded Column1" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Converted to Table", "Column1", {"id", "url", "html_url", "number", "user", "original_author", "original_author_id", "title", "body", "ref", "labels", "milestone", "assignee", "assignees", "state", "is_locked", "comments", "created_at", "updated_at", "closed_at", "due_date", "pull_request", "repository"}, {"id", "url", "html_url", "number", "user", "original_author", "original_author_id", "title", "body", "ref", "labels", "milestone", "assignee", "assignees", "state", "is_locked", "comments", "created_at", "updated_at", "closed_at", "due_date", "pull_request", "repository"})
in
    #"Expanded Column1"
```

Comment: This still results in the error I have mentioned in the post.

Comment: @caleb you may have to qualify the range with a worksheet like `Sheets("Sheet name").Range("B1")`

Comment: I think the issue is caused by something else

Comment: @caleb - see update, the url needs to be quoted so i have added "".

Comment: This answer could be drastically improved by describing the  necessary changes and giving a reasoning behind why they are needed. Even just a short sentence for each change would greatly improve the quality of this answer.

Comment: Even after trying this, the same error: "Run-time error '1004':
[Expression.Error] The name 'Source' wasn't recognized. Make sure its spelled correctly. "

Comment: @CDP1802 Could you explain the purpose of the triple quotes inside the Json.Document(Web.Contents()) line? My thinking was that the function Web.Contents can only take in literal strings and not variables containing strings or cells that reference the string. Please feel free to correct me if this is wrong. I think that attempting to "force" the function to accept a reference to a string is causing the error I had mentioned.

Comment: @Caleb When I created a web Query and then used `Debug.Print Thisworkbook.Queries(1).Formula` I get `Source = Web.Page(Web.Contents("http://...."))` where the url is quoted as a string parameter to `Web.Contents()`. Formula is a string and you need to build that string by concatinating other strings, hence all the &'s. The `& "    Source"` you have at the end looks odd, is that where you edited the recorded macro ?

Comment: @CDP1802 I believe it is;  in case it was an error I replaced the code in the post with the most up to date VBA code. please give it a look.

Comment: @Caleb Ok, i have run you code and I can see an error in the Power Query editor. There is a comma required after the brackets here `""")),"`. Note you can't add a query if there is an existing one with the same name.

Comment: @CDP1802 Thanks! After playing around with that for a while It finally works! I had to modify a bit more code but used your fix to get to that point. I finally ended up needing to change this line:
`ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "http://URL"`

to this:
`ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
          Range("B1").Value`

Answer (score 0):

This is the code that ended up working for me:

```
Sub JsonToExcel()
'
' JsonToExcel Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+J
'
    ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add Name:= _
        "issues?state=open&access_token=", _
        Formula:= _
        "let" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Source = Json.Document(Web.Contents(""" & Sheets("Sheet1").Range("$B$1").Value & """))," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Converted to Table"" = Table.FromList(Source, Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error)," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Expanded Column1"" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#""Converted to Tab" & _
        "le"", ""Column1"", {""id"", ""url"", ""html_url"", ""number"", ""user"", ""original_author"", ""original_author_id"", ""title"", ""body"", ""ref"", ""labels"", ""milestone"", ""assignee"", ""assignees"", ""state"", ""is_locked"", ""comments"", ""created_at"", ""updated_at"", ""closed_at"", ""due_date"", ""pull_request"", ""repository""}, {""id"", ""url"", ""html_url" & _
        """, ""number"", ""user"", ""original_author"", ""original_author_id"", ""title"", ""body"", ""ref"", ""labels"", ""milestone"", ""assignee"", ""assignees"", ""state"", ""is_locked"", ""comments"", ""created_at"", ""updated_at"", ""closed_at"", ""due_date"", ""pull_request"", ""repository""})" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "in" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Expanded Column1"""
    Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
    With ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:=Array( _
        "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location=""issues?state=open&access_token=" _
        , "29f0ca0d90"";Extended Properties="""""), Destination:=Range("$A$1")). _
        QueryTable
        .CommandType = xlCmdSql
        .CommandText = Array( _
        "SELECT * FROM [issues?state=open&access_token=]" _
        )
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .PreserveColumnInfo = False
        .ListObject.DisplayName = _
        "issues_state_open_access_token_"
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
    Selection.ListObject.QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    Range("issues_state_open_access_token_" _
        ).Select
    Range("B2").Activate
    With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlGeneral
        .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
        .WrapText = True
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .IndentLevel = 0
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
        .MergeCells = False
    End With
End Sub
```

With the token numbers left intentionally blank